# How do you force Internet Explorer to load the Adobe Flash Content Debugger?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I currently have the latest version of the IE Flash Player Installed:

[image]
[image]

I've installed the latest version of the content debugger from [The Adobe Flash Player Support Center](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

Regardless of what I do IE doesn't seem to pick up the new content debugger version.  I've tried uninstalling, tried installing an older version... All with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem ended up being I was executing ie64 which was only picking up the installed 64bit version and ignored my installation of the 32bit debugger.

Don't I feel silly...

Answer (score 0):

There is no 64bit debugger version. If you only install the debugger version you will not have Flash Player in IE64, but if you install in IE64 it will overwrite the debugger version! What you need to do is install the standard 64bit version *then* the 32bit debugger version. They need to be the latest versions or you will have to use the workaround below. Unfortunately, if you have both versions installed you get a warning message every time you debug, but it works. If you debug with Firefox you will not have this problem.

Just to make sure you have the right debugger version, it's the one labelled **ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)**. Currently it's the first file under the Windows heading:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

The version labelled **Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers)** is the one for Firefox. I think the other 2 versions are for standalone apps.

Then you need to make sure that Flash Builder is using the 32bit version of Internet Explorer. Go to Flash Builder > Preferences > General > Web Browser. You should see 2 versions of Internet Explorer, click Edit to find the version that is in the **Program Files (x86)** folder not the **Program Files** folder, of course.

It seems that Adobe have changed the installer recently to allow having both versions, but it still reads the 64bit version in the registry, hence the popup.

---

If there is still a problem you may have to do things the old-fashioned way. This was a necessary workaround to have the older 32bit debugger and 64bit standard versions installed:

Install the 32-bit debugger version of Flash

Back-up the files in Windows\sysWOW64\Macromed\Flash folder to another folder (these are the debugger files)

Install the standard 64bit Flash Player: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer

Rename the Windows\sysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash11e.ocx file because file permissions will not let you overwrite it (you could 'take ownership' if you prefer)

Copy the backed-up debugger files back to **Windows\sysWOW64\Macromed\Flash** to overwrite the standard 32bit files (not **Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash**, these are the 64-bit files).

Again you need to make sure that Flash Builder is using the 32bit version of Internet Explorer, as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

I once had the same problem, and here is how I got it working...

- Use the below special uninstaller:
  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html#main_Download_the_Adobe_Flash_Player_uninstaller
- Check IE if the plugin still exists, and if so, use this process to delete the plugin: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2612/ie7_remove_disable_add_ons_activex_plugins/
- Reboot
- Download and install the latest debug version:
  http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_ax_debug_32bit.exe
- restart IE

I hope this works for you as it did for me!

Comment: Nope.  It worked to uninstall the plugin, but even after running the installer the new version still does not appear in IE.

Comment: Did you use IE to specifically delete the activex plugin using step 2?

Comment: In the screenshot, it shows that it's using Flash64 (64bit Flash). This version does not support debugging. Are you sure your installing the 32bit debug version?

Comment: This article might help to force IE to use the 32but debugger: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3974657

Comment: there is no 64bit version of the debugger... the only option is to install the 32bit version (and yes that's what i've been doing).  Thanks for the article link, i'll give that a shot

Comment: after reviewing the article you sent me, it's one I found during my initial investigation and unfortunately provides no details on a solution other than what I've already tried.

One of the commenters mentions Chrome, to install the content debugger for chrome I installed the 'netscape compatible' version from The Adobe site which did work in chrome once i disabled the native flash version... it still doesn't work in IE though and that's where I need it.